Are these elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ isogenous?
I have the following elliptic curves:
$$E:y^2=x^3-\sqrt{2}x \quad \quad E':y^2=x^3-2x$$
over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. I want to determine whether they are isogenous.
I have a few strategies to do this when the field I am working on is finite (for example counting points) or when the field is the complex numbers (mainly looking at the lattices). However, when looking at number fields like this one I am completely lost. I am only able to prove that they are isomorphic over the algebraic closure of my field since they have the same $j$-invariant, but this does not tell me that they are isomorphic over the number field itself. I have tried manually constructing an isogeny but this took me nowhere. But I also don't know how to show that such an isogeny does not exist. Can someone show me how to proceed in this case?

In this case, you can exploit the fact that the curves become isomorphic over $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[8]2)$. Let $\psi\colon E\to E'$ be an isomorphism over $K$, and suppose that $\phi\colon E\to E'$ is an isogeny defined over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$.
Then, over $K$, the map $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi$ would have to be an endomorphism of $E$, defined over $K$.
But, even though $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(E) = \mathbb Z[i]$ (via the isomorphism $(x, y)\mapsto (-x,iy)$), crucially, the extra endomorphisms are not defined over $K$. Hence, $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi$ must be multiplication by $n$ for some integer $n$. In particular, over $K$, $\ker\phi = \ker([n])$, which would imply that $\phi = [n]$... but that would    mean that $E$ and $E'$ are already isomorphic over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$, which they are not. (For example, they have different $2$-torsion, because the polynomial $x^3 - 2x$ splits into linear factors, while $x^3 - \sqrt 2x$ does not.)
It might be helpful to see how this argument can go wrong with $E$ replaced with $y^2 = x^3 +8x$ and both $E, E'$ viewed over $\mathbb Q$. This time, $E$ and $E'$ become isomorphic over $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{-4})$, which contains $\mathbb Q(i)$. In particular, if $\phi\colon E\to E'$ is an isogeny over $\mathbb Q$, and $\psi\colon E\to E'$ is an isogeny over $K$, then it's still the case that $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi\in \mathrm{End}_K(E)$, but this time, it could be any element of $\mathbb Z[i]$. In particular, it can be $1 + i$. Note that $(1+i)^2 = 2i$, so $(1+i)$ is an endomorphism which applied twice gives you multiplication by $2i$. It turns out that this endomorphism over $K$ descends to a cyclic $2$-isogeny over $\mathbb Q$.

Hello! First I want to thank you for your answer. I have a couple of questions. First, I would like to know why you know that $\operatorname{End}(E)=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In general, I am not good at computing the endomorphism ring of an elliptic curve that is not over the complex numbers, so any help will be appreciated

Then you also say that "the extra endomorphisms are not defined over $K$". I also don't understand this part, nor why can you conclude that $\psi^{-1}\circ \phi$ must be multiplication by $n$ for some $n$. Could you maybe include the details in your answer? Thanks!

I added a description of the CM in this case. You can also see from the definition that the map is only defined over fields containing $\mathbb Q(i)$. Over $K$, the endomorphism ring is just $\mathbb Z$, so $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi$ has to just be multiplication by an integer.

Sorry this still doesn't really say anything to me. I still don't understand why the endomorphism ring is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

The map $(x, y)\mapsto(-x, iy)$ is an endomorphism of $E$, which when applied twice, gives $(x, y)\mapsto (x,-y)$, which is just $[-1]$. So this map at least gives you an embedding of $\mathbb Z[i]$ into the endomorphism ring of $E$. Then, the standard theory, which says over a field of characteristic $0$, $\mathrm{End}(E)$ is either $\mathbb Z$ or an order in an imaginary quadratic field tells you that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is the entire endomorphism ring.

I understand what you ae saying except for the end. I see that $\operatorname{End}(E)$ has to be an order in an imaginary quadratic field. I don't see why this implies that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the entire endomorphism ring

@user297024 done

@kubo $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a ring of integers, so a maximal order

Thanks for the edits, it's a bit clearer now. I have one more question. I still don't see why you can claim that over $K$, the endomorphism ring is just $\mathbb{Z}$. Why is it not an order in an imaginary quadratic field?

This is something that just follows from the theory of CM elliptic curves. In particular, over a non-CM field (e.g. a field with real embeddings), it's impossible for an elliptic curve to have extra endomorphisms.

What do you mean exactly with "extra endomorphisms"?
